# SDL2 is not linking anymore on macOS Big Sur (M1)

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl-2, apple-m1, macos-big-sur

I have created a small **C++ SDL2** project with CMake under **macOS Big Sur (m1)**.

This is the **CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.2)

project(sdl2gamepad)

add_library(sdl2lib SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET sdl2lib PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "/opt/homebrew/lib/libSDL2.dylib")

include_directories("/opt/homebrew/include")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${sdl2lib})
```

I installed **SDL2** and **CMake** with homebrew.

The project was initially compiled and linked with the Makefile without problems and I was able to run it.

I then wanted to structure my project with an `src` and `build` folder and had adapted the `CMakeLists.txt`. Unfortunately, CMake/Make was no longer able to link the SDL2 lib.

Linking error message:

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable sdl2gamepad
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_SDL_CreateWindow", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_SDL_DestroyWindow", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_SDL_GetError", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_SDL_GetWindowSurface", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_SDL_Init", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_SDL_LoadBMP_RW", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_SDL_PollEvent", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_SDL_Quit", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_SDL_RWFromFile", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_SDL_UpdateWindowSurface", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_SDL_UpperBlit", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [sdl2gamepad] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/sdl2gamepad.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I then reset the CMakeLists.txt to the status where it had worked (code above). But unfortunately, the problem still exists.

But I can compile the code with this command, it is probably due to a CMake misconfiguration.

```
$ clang++ main.cpp -o main /opt/homebrew/lib/libSDL2.dylib -I /opt/homebrew/include
```

CMake Version is **3.22.2**.
SDL2 Version is **2.0.20**.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Expression `${sdl2lib}` dereferences a **variable** named `sdl2lib`, which is not defined in your project. The command `add_library(sdl2lib SHARED IMPORTED)` creates a **target** named `sdl2lib`. For link with the target do not dereference its name: `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE sdl2lib)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you!! That solved the problem. Thanks also for the explanation.